# My app can't show on google play store on Samsung Note 8

Tags: android, google-play, samsung-mobile

I did some research on it. Finally I think it's due to the compatible-screens is not set correctly for Note 8. But I don't know what I should set. Please give some help.

The config is as below,

```
<compatible-screens>
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />

    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="560"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="640"
        android:screenSize="normal" />

    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />

    <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />

    <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="213"
        android:screenSize="large" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Comment: If you want to support all screen sizes, you do not need to set any compatible-screens as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't have any **xxhdpi** or **xxxhdpi** densities on your list. It means, your app will not work on many of the devices. **Note 8** model has **xxhdpi** density also.

If you want to support all screen sizes, you do not need to set any compatible-screens. Only use this, if you want to limit some screen sizes.

There is an important note for `compatible-screens` article.

> **Caution:** Normally, you should not use this manifest element. Using
>   this element can dramatically reduce the potential user base for your
>   application, by not allowing users to install your application if they
>   have a device with a screen configuration that you have not listed.
>   You should use it only as a last resort, when the application
>   absolutely does not work with specific screen configurations. Instead
>   of using this element, you should follow the guide to [Supporting
>   Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) to provide scalable support for multiple screens
>   using alternative layouts and bitmaps for different screen sizes and
>   densities.

[**Source**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html)